No name 'Main' in module 'juliacall'
I have an interesting problem where the line from juliacall import Main as jl shows an error in both Pylint and Pylance (VSCode). Is this just a linter issue and if so, can it be resolved (other than disabling)?
No name 'Main' in module 'juliacall' Pylint(E0611:no-name-in-module)
"Main" is unknown import symbol Pylance(reportAttributeAccessIssue)

Furthermore, if the import statement is placed at the top of the file, the code also hangs at runtime (no error messages). Putting the import statement inside each function resolves this, but no idea why.
(.venv) C:\myproj>pip show JuliaCall
Name: juliacall
Version: 0.9.23
Summary: Julia and Python in seamless harmony
Home-page: http://github.com/JuliaPy/PythonCall.jl
Author:
Author-email:
License:
Location: c:\myproj\.venv\Lib\site-packages
Requires: juliapkg
Required-by:
(.venv) C:\myproj>python --version
Python 3.12.4


I think it is just a weird linter thing where linters don’t understand virtual environments. From a quick DuckDuckGo search, it seems that this is a thing with linters not understanding virtual environments. Perhaps the linter program itself isn’t being run in the virtual environment or it was activated in the environment where the linter was run. This seems more likely in the case of PyLance where VSCode doesn’t, as I said, doesn’t activate (or detect) virtual environments in the environment where PyLance is to be run.

@DeepThought42 If that were the case I'd expect to see errors for all external libraries, but I don't.

Fair, but perhaps not if the library is also installed in the global environment (/usr/lib/python/ etc. ). I’m kinda guessing at this point but I solve most of my errors and bugs by doing this.

@DeepThought42 pip list indicates no. If it wasn't installed (in venv) then it wouldn't work at all during runtime.


Reinstall juliacall using pip;
Verify if there is a different Julia set as default (altough juliacall should install one locally);
If problem still persists, try making a new Julia package (doesn't require Main call explicitly):


import juliacall
jl = juliacall.newmodule("SomeName")
from array import array
jl.seval("using Statistics")
x = array('i', [1, 2, 3])
jl.println(jl.mean(x))

worked on my VScode.
For more information visit their site: https://juliapy.github.io/PythonCall.jl/stable/juliacall/
